# Selenium chrome driver can't be found when added to eclipse as maven dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, m2e, selenium-chromedriver

I am using m2e eclipse plugin in 4.2 Juno.  I see the selenium-chrome-driver-2.26.0.jar file in my maven dependencies after adding

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.26.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file.  I get the typical missing driver error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable 
must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; ...
```

The firefox driver works (it's automatic).  I am able to successfully update my project with the Maven sub menu when right clicking on the project.  The maven dependecy folder is already added to my project's build path. I've looked at posts similar to these with not much luck.

[How to add maven repository jars to eclipse buildpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972770/how-to-add-maven-repository-jars-to-eclipse-buildpath)
[How to configure Eclipse build path to use Maven dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037188/how-to-configure-eclipse-build-path-to-use-maven-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the ChromeDriver class.

You need to download the latest version of chrome driver from [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

Extract the zip and you will find a .exe file.

Use the following code
 `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<path to Chromedriver .exe>");`

Else set PATH environment variable pointing to location of ChromeDriver.exe

Comment: I see, Maven is not that magical. I'm clearly a java n00b. Thanks.